# How to Get the "Request PayLoad" data using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, .net-2.0

I am using vb.net 2.0 and asp.net in my project.

I am sending ajax request from a page to get response.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetMyData.aspx?i=2",
            data: '{ugData: \"10\"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               alert(response.d);
                return false;
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
```

In this code, after ajax request I can see that the variable  "ugData" is in the **Request Payload** in Developers tool.

Can any one help me out How can i able to read this "ugData" variable value in my Page "GetMyData.aspx".

Thank You..

Comment: Yes...Once I will get the Requested data fro m My Page.. i will Add the Sucess function logic.. but before that  I cant able to Read the value of ugData variable in my page side..

Comment: Actually I am not aware of How to Get that ugData value on GetMyData.aspx Page..This is my query that how can i Get this ugData on serverside ..